# Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, https

I dida wcf username/password authentication  on my local computer, with self signed certificate, all works fine, but when i put my  application on IIS 7.5, and windows server 2008 R2, it gaves me the error:
**Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].** 
My web service cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceCredentialsBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="cn=AmicCert" storeName="Root" storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Util.CustomUserNameValidator, Util" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceCredentialsBehavior" name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageAndUserName" name="SecuredByTransportEndpoint" contract="IService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MessageAndUserName">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
      <client />
   </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
 </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: What it worked for me address="mex" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285717/why-do-i-need-both-mex-endpoint-and-httpgetenable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like the IIS web site instance you're hosting under is only configured for HTTPS (SSL). Right click the web site instance and choose "Edit Bindings...". Do you see port 80 (plain HTTP) listed there? Also check the "SSL Settings" feature to make sure the "Always require" option is not turned on.

Comment: There is only one binding, and that is on port 8010(port forwarding), should i create another binding with 80 port and without https?

Comment: Port doesn't matter, but there has to be an non-HTTPS/SSL address bound to the site because you're not using transport security (only message security) in your config.

Comment: Your AmiCert certificate must not be installed in the store on the server yet.

Comment: I had a WCF service that was working perfectly with a server cert, client message auth (user/pass), and then stopped working, displaying this error, after I updated my server certificate. I only changed the thumbprint on the server config. Has anyone encountered that?

Answer (score 10):

Drew's answer is correct if you don't want to use HTTPS/SSL for the endpoint.

If you do want to use SSL over the endpoint, you need to change your:

```
<security mode="Message">
```

to:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it work and still having the IIS to require SSL, you need to make some changes in your endpoint in the config file: Set the `address` property to the service's address with https (`https://...`) and the `listenUri` property to the service's address with http (`http://...`). This applies to both `wsHttp` and `basicHttp`.

Comment: I don't have a protocol specified in my endpoint, so this isn't it.