# Set WCF Service endpoints at server side web config for https

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am stuck in very odd situation and do not know how to solve this issue.

I have very simple WCF service working very fine with http BUT now I want to move it to https.

The issue is Server where it needs to be hosted. Server IIS have an alias name "server-test.local" (not "localhost") with http. Its is accessible locally with this alias name. And its mapped to a Domain name with https (example, https://rmt.XXXXXXX.com).

When I deploy my WCF to that server and check WSDL file, it has mapping of the local alias name instead of public domain name.

it is showing http://server-test.local/WCFService/Service.svc  (WRONG)

I want mapping like https://rmt.XXXXXXXX.com/WCFService/Service.svc (CORRECT)

**Service web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
   </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I add service reference to app. It adds following endpoint which is not conrrect.

**Client App.config (endpoint)**

```
<endpoint address="http://server-test.local/WCFService/Service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProcessing"
        contract="WCFService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProcessing" />
```

I am able to access the url and WSDL file through browser but not able to consume any Service methods. I am getting error **"There is no endpoint which can accept the message."**

I think I am missing something obvious here. Please suggest me changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change some simple steps in the web.config file, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611514/wcf-binding-to-https) for details.
1.Enable transport level security in the web.config file of the service:

```
<security mode="Transport">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
```

2.Use the `bindingConfiguration` tag to specify the binding name and the `behaviorConfiguration` tag to configure the behavior, and then specify the address of the managed service. The code is as follows:

```
<service name="***" behaviorConfiguration="***">
    <endpoint address= https://rmt.XXXXXXXX.com/WCFService/Service.svc 
      binding="basicHttpBinding"  
      bindingConfiguration="???" 
      contract="WCFService.IService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```